# Problem Installing git kubuntu

Tags: software-installation, git

I have installed both `git` and `git-core` using:

```
sudo apt-get install git git-core
```

Still, when I try to run some git command on terminal, I get the following error message:

```
The program 'git' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install git
```

I tried again and again, but I always get the same error. This also happened when I tried removing and reinstalling git.

How do I get git to work?

Comment: "when i try to run *some* git command"?  Does it only work with *some* commands?  If so, please provide a few examples of what does and does not work.

Comment: even simply typing git says me that git is not installed,

Comment: when i run sudo apt-get install git, i get message:  git is already the newest version.
git set to manually installed.

Comment: Please run `oneconf-query | grep git` and `which git` and create a comment with the results.

Comment: i get output :
git
git-core
git-man
git-gui
gitk 

which git didnt return anything

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge git`.  This command will remove git completely, as it appears that you have a corrupted installation.  Then attempt to reinstall git using `sudo apt-get install git`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to reflect all the details you posted in the comments. Also add the result of the latest [@fouric’s advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258471/problem-installing-git-kubuntu#comment323208_258471). If you have solved your problem already or it is no more relevant, please close or delete your question.